# Data of the quick links report on Branch.io is not accessible

Tags: branch.io

I've been working on Branch for a while. However for the past 10 days, I've got an error message that blocks me from accessing my "quick links" data.
The message is saying: "Your data is taking too long to load. Please try again, refresh, or reduce your time period. Error requesting data. Please try again."
I'm loading, and loading, and loading, and it's working once every 50 attempts.
Do you know if there is anything to do to make it work again?
Could it be because i've created 20 quick links in the past 2 weeks?
Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

A Branchster here -

There could be multiple reasons for this error including what filters have you currently set on the Dashboard and the date range for which you are looking at the data.
Ideally, you can start by limiting the date range of the data view and you can Inspect your Browser if there are any network failures. If the issue persists, you can try signing out and logging in back to the Dashboard.

If this doesn't resolve it for you, please reach out to us - https://help.branch.io/using-branch/page/submit-a-support-ticket